# Send Instruction with multiple parameters to non-anchor program help (instruciton_data)

Tags: transactions, testing, instructions, data

I am working with a solana program which was written a couple years ago and it is non-anchor.  I am specifically having trouble with calling the program functions from the test-side, the data field with Buffer Layout is causing me problems.  I will show one function here from the program and how I am trying to interact with it, along with the error:

Rust src/instruction.rs:

```
  /* Inits a new lock schedule.
    *  A lock schedule consists of a LockScheduleHeader and array of LockSchedule s.
    *  The header consists of destination address, token mint address and initialized flag.
    *  LockTokenInstruction::Init instruction creates a program account from the seeds array which has data size to fit the number of schedule data.
    *
    *  - Accounts
    *  0. `[]` The system program account
    *  1. `[]` Program state account
    *  2. `[]` The sysvar Rent account
    *  3. `[signer]` The fee payer account
    *  4. `[]` The locking account
    */
    Init {
        seeds: [u8; 32],
        number_of_schedules: u32,
    },
```

This would be instruction index 0.  That function calls this in src/processor.rs:

```
 pub fn process_init(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &[AccountInfo],
        seeds: [u8; 32],
        schedules: u32
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

        let system_program_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let program_state_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let rent_sysvar_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let payer = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
        let locking_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

        let rent = Rent::from_account_info(rent_sysvar_account)?;

        let program_state_account_key = Pubkey::create_program_address(&[String::from(OWNER_TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS).as_bytes()], program_id)?;

        if program_state_account_key != *program_state_account.key {
            msg!("Provided program state account is invalid");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
        }

        let is_state_initialized = program_state_account.try_borrow_data()?[LockGlobalState::LEN - 1] == 1;

        if !is_state_initialized {
            msg!("The state of program is uninitialized");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
        }

        let program_global_state = LockGlobalState::unpack(&program_state_account.data.borrow())?;

        if program_global_state.is_paused {
            msg!("The program is paused");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
        }

        let locking_account_key = Pubkey::create_program_address(&[&seeds], &program_id).unwrap();
        if locking_account_key != *locking_account.key {
            msg!("Provided locking account is invalid");
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
        }

        let state_size = (schedules as usize) * LockSchedule::LEN + LockScheduleHeader::LEN;

        let init_locking_account = create_account(
            &payer.key,
            &locking_account_key,
            rent.minimum_balance(state_size),
            state_size as u64,
            &program_id,
        );

        invoke_signed(
            &init_locking_account,
            &[
                system_program_account.clone(),
                payer.clone(),
                locking_account.clone(),
            ],
            &[&[&seeds]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

So it has two arguments, seeds: [u8; 32] and size: u32.
Here is the javascript I am using to test this:

```
  it('can initialize', async () => {
    let payer = Keypair.generate();

    let airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      payer.publicKey,
      LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    );
    
    let airdropTx = await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
    console.log("airdrop: " + airdropTx);

      /* Inits a new lock schedule.
    *  A lock schedule consists of a LockScheduleHeader and array of LockSchedule s.
    *  The header consists of destination address, token mint address and initialized flag.
    *  LockTokenInstruction::Init instruction creates a program account from the seeds array which has data size to fit the number of schedule data.
    *
    *  - Accounts
    *  0. `[]` The system program account
    *  1. `[]` Program state account
    *  2. `[]` The sysvar Rent account
    *  3. `[signer]` The fee payer account
    *  4. `[]` The locking account
    */
   let programState = Keypair.generate();
   let lockingAccnt = Keypair.generate();


  let seeds = new BN(32).toArray("le", 32);

  const dataLayout = BufferLayout.struct([
    BufferLayout.u8('instruction'),
    BufferLayout.u32('seeds'), // I don't think this is right; should be [u8; 32] but can't find that
    BufferLayout.u32('number_of_schedules')
  ]);
  const data = Buffer.alloc(dataLayout.span);
  dataLayout.encode(
    {
      instruction: 0, // 0 for create instruction,
      seeds: seeds,
      number_of_schedules: new BN(3),
    },
    data,
  );

  // Allocating space and rent for source token account
  const createPState = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: programState.publicKey,
    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    programId: lockProgram,
    space: 64,
  });

  const createLAcc = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: lockingAccnt.publicKey,
    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    programId: lockProgram,
    space: 64,
  });

  const initTx = new TransactionInstruction({
    programId: lockProgram,
    keys: [
        { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: programState.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false},
        { pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: lockingAccnt.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },

    ],
    data: data
})     
console.log(initTx);
    const tx = new Transaction()
        .add(initTx, createLAcc, createPState);
let confTx = await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [payer, lockingAccnt, programState], {skipPreflight: false, preflightCommitment: 'confirmed'})
.then(()=>{console.log("done")}).catch((e)=>{console.log("error",e)});;

console.log(confTx);

  });
```

I am running these tests with Anchor.  The error message I get is a panic from data, which I am assuming is from the Buffer Layout not being formatted correctly:

```
airdrop: [object Object]
TransactionInstruction {
  keys: [
    { pubkey: [PublicKey], isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: [PublicKey], isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: [PublicKey], isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: [PublicKey], isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: [PublicKey], isSigner: false, isWritable: true }
  ],
  programId: PublicKey {
    _bn: <BN: 7894a05db0bdd9c31ee41a2478180850e493525f76e7b06fa3f67c80961c6e63>
  },
  data: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00>
}
error SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/mnt/c/Users/user/rust/solana/program/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4546:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Connection.sendRawTransaction (/mnt/c/Users/user/rust/solana/program/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4505:20)
    at Connection.sendTransaction (/mnt/c/Users/user/rust/solana/program/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4493:12) {
  logs: [
    'Program 97hNSfjmUz1y9rurSmu5pKKMpP65n8owuq3RoqxCCD54 invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Entrypoint',
    'Program log: Beginning processing',
    "Program log: panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/instruction.rs:112:22",
    'Program 97hNSfjmUz1y9rurSmu5pKKMpP65n8owuq3RoqxCCD54 consumed 2979 of 600000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: BPF program panicked',
    'Program 97hNSfjmUz1y9rurSmu5pKKMpP65n8owuq3RoqxCCD54 failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]
}
```

That error occurs on the 'none' value which is coming from data.  I have three main questions about this:

1. How can I format data correctly?  How can I use Buffer Layout for seeds when it is unavailble to use uint arrays for the data field?
2. Would I be better off rewriting this as an anchor program?  I can handle that easily since it provides an idl and the program. workspace.
3. Is there an easier way to do these transactions for non-anchor programs?

I really appreciate any help I get here.  I know this is a lot to take in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like `BufferLayout.blob(32, 'seeds')` instead.

The error is occurring because an `Option<T>::None` is being `unwrap()`ed on line 112.  There are no line numbers on the processor code that you've provided, but `unwrap()` is only called on `Pubkey::create_program_account()`'s result, so odds are your seeds don't resolved to a valid PDA.  Looking at your client code, there's no call to (whatever is the JS equivalent of) `Pubkey::find_program_address()`, which would be required to reliably choose seeds.  I'd suggest giving the [cookbook article about PDAs](https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#how-to-create-pdas) and all of its references a read to better understand what might be going wrong here